# APFS or JHFS+ for dual boot MacOSX Mojave / Fedora?

Tags: macos, multi-boot, fedora, macos-mojave

What filesystem, APFS or JHFS+ is needed for a dual boot system on Mac, OSX Mojave / Fedora? Will Fedora install into APFS?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Fedora Installer (from flash) does not see an extra jhfs+ partition disk0s3. So over the next several days I will try hfs+ or fat32. Too bad I found no information on required file system in fedora docs.